# Сделать аббревиатуру из предложения

Tags: c#

На вход дается текст. Выведите вместе первые буквы каждого слова (сделать аббревиатуру). Буквы необходимо выводить большими. Нужно сделать через регулярку. Помогите как-то исправить  мой код пожалуйста !

```
string s = "asdc bcsdc cfgc";
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\w.");
MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(s);
if (matches.Count > 0)
    foreach (Match match in matches)
    {
        Console.Write(match);// Должно вывести ABC
}
```

Comment: В чем проблема то? Что не получается?

Comment: Какие строки у вас на входе и выходе? Как вы отличите дату от всего остального?

Comment: https://regex101.com `\w+`

Comment: что вы считаете за слово? "царевна-лягушка" это одно или 2 слова?

Comment: Будем считать за слово ели после него идет пробел

Comment: Проблема в том что программа не выводит первую букву первого слова

Comment: И еще одно, как сделать чтобы буквы выводились все с большого регистра ?

Comment: Не пишите дополнительную информацию в комментарии, пишите прямо в вопрос, а комментарии удалите

Comment: `@"\w+"` - регулярка, которая вам нужна. Взять первую букву слова: `[0]`. Перевести символ в верхний регистр: `char.ToUpper`. Дерзайте.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(string.Concat(Regex.Split(s, @"\W+").Where(x => x.Length > 0).Select(x => x[0])).ToUpper())`

Comment: Господи, а регулярки-то тут зачем??

Comment: В условии было написано сделать через регулярку

Comment: Просто скажите мне что писать в new Regex(@" ")

Answer (score 6):

Режем строку по пробелам и другим символам, попутно удаляя пустые строки и обрезая пробелы в каждой полученной подстроке. Далее всё просто - берём в каждой подстроке первый символ, преобразуем его к верхнему регистру и полученные символы преобразуем обратно в строку.

```cs
string s = "asdc.,, bcsdc.,, cfgc,.";
string[] parts = s.Split(new char[]{' ', '.', ','},
    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries |
    StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries);
string result = String.Concat(parts.Select(part => char.ToUpper(part[0])));
```

Поиграться можно [здесь](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pltleF).